# How is the memory used by IBOutlets managed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have several outlets in most of my view controllers and I always link them up with properties in the header file like this:

```
IBOutlet UIButton *homeButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *homeButton;
```

Should I be using assign here since I assume that the memory is being handled by the NIB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quote from [Resource Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW6):

> Objects in the nib file are created
>   with a retain count of 1 and then
>   autoreleased. As it rebuilds the
>   object hierarchy, however, UIKit
>   reestablishes connections between the
>   objects using the setValue:forKey:
>   method, which uses the available
>   setter method or retains the object by
>   default if no setter method is
>   available. **If you define outlets for
>   nib-file objects, you should always
>   define a setter method (or declared
>   property) for accessing that outlet.
>   Setter methods for outlets should
>   retain their values, and setter
>   methods for outlets containing
>   top-level objects must retain their
>   values to prevent them from being
>   deallocated.** If you do not store the
>   top-level objects in outlets, you must
>   retain either the array returned by
>   the loadNibNamed:owner:options: method
>   or the objects inside the array to
>   prevent those objects from being
>   released prematurely.

There you can find more details on how objects are loaded from nib file, but in short - no, you must use retaining properties for your IBOutlets.

Comment: +1. Also note that there are several nasty bugs that can crop up if you don't retain. I've spent lots of time in debugging after some memory warning hit...

Comment: I have just checked now and it seems the buttons that are outlets have a retain count of 3 and I am not allocation memory anywhere in the application to them.  They only exist in the nib and define as above.  This surely can't be right?!

Comment: You should not rely on retainCount as an object can be retained by any other else (and released as well), the main thing is that all retains and releases should be paired. Retain count 3 may come from: 1 - from your setter, 2 - retained by superview, 3rd retain could come from registering for target action (not sure though) or by some operation that runs meanwhile

Comment: But the only important thing is that you should release an object if you retain it - if you do that, then you do memory management right. For outlets you should also nil them in -viewDidUnload controller method to get rid of them when low memory warning comes

Answer (score -2):

You just release the iboutlets object in delloc